# SMTP: Received from unknown [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] -> but IP does have a valid PTR/RDNS

Tags: domain-name-system, email, postfix, email-server, reverse-dns

I got the following problem. I got an `smtp-relayserver` that collects outgoing mails from other servers and checks them (spam assassin).

Now the headers are showing this:

```
Received: from customerdomain.com (unknown [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx])
     (using TLSv1.2 with cipher AECDH-AES256-SHA (256/256 bits))
     (No client certificate requested)
     by relayserver.com (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 1D576101747
     for <myexample@receipient.com>; Fri, 29 Apr 2016 21:11:14 +0200 (CEST)
Received: from XYZ (some-isp.com [xx.xx.xx.xx])
     by outgoing-mailserver.com (Postfix) with ESMTPA id C684DAC4F2F
     for < myexample@receipient.com >; Fri, 29 Apr 2016 21:11:13 +0200 (CEST)
```

Okay, fine - my first thought: the IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is missing a RDNS.

But

```
host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
results in
outgoing-mailserver.com
```

Why is it showing the `unknown`-tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://grox.net/doc/postfix/html/faq.html#paranoid

> warning: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: address not listed for hostname yyy.yyy.yyy
>
> Postfix uses hostnames in its junk mail and mail relay controls. This
>   means that in theory someone could be motivated to set up bogus DNS
>   information, in order to get past your junk mail or mail relay
>   controls. When Postfix looks up the SMTP client hostname for the SMTP
>   client IP address, then Postfix also checks if the SMTP client IP
>   address is listed under the SMTP client hostname.
>
> If the SMTP client IP address is not listed under the SMTP client
>   hostname, then Postfix concludes that the SMTP client hostname does
>   not belong to the SMTP client IP address, and ignores the SMTP client
>   hostname. A warning is logged, so that you can find out why an SMTP
>   client is or is not stopped by your junk mail or mail relay checks.
>
> You could contact the people who maintain the SMTP client's DNS
>   records, and explain to them that each IP address needs one PTR
>   record, and that this one PTR record needs a matching A record.
>
> Some people read the RFCs such that one IP address can have multiple
>   PTR records, but that makes PTR records even less useful than they
>   already are. And in any case, having multiple names per IP address
>   only worsens the problem of finding out the SMTP client hostname.